# Работа с большими числами

Tags: c, длинная-арифметика

Пишу программу в visual studio cls проект. Там есть textbox. Ребят подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеку для работы с большими числами. Чтобы можно было конвектировать из textbox в большое число, и чтобы можно было этой переменной выделять память для массива. Пробовал библиотеку boost, там этими переменами нельзя выделять память под массивы.

Comment: Что означает "можно было этой переменной выделять память для массива"?

Comment: Через оператор New. Для векторов память

Comment: Еще раз: что означает "можно было этой переменной выделять память для массива"? Где в операторе `new[]` должны фигурировать эти "большие числа"? Размер массива? Тип элемента массива? Еще где-то?

Comment: Размер массива надо

Comment: Размер массива??? Размер массива в С и С++ обязан помещаться в обычный стандартный тип `size_t`. Если ваш размер не помещается в `size_t`, то выделить такой массив через `new[]` вы никогда не сможете. Никакие "большие числа" вам в этом никак не помогут. и никакие библиотеки больших чисел вам здесь ни к чему. На 64-битной платформе тип `size_t` уже обычно 64-битный. И сделать массив большего размера на такой платформе невозможно в принципе.

Comment: Я понимаю, просто если в переменную большого числа поместить маленькое число, он все равно не выделит память

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно взять любую понравившеюся имплементацию BigInt. А можно самому написать, и реализовать все математические операции на числами. Но проще первое.

Для C - https://github.com/dandclark/BigInt

Для C++ - http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22566?locale=ru

Comment: Там как я понял, нет отрицательных чисел?

Comment: Посмотри внимательно на код. Там есть флаг отвечающий за знак.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то мне тоже понадобилась длинная арифметика. Но использовать GMP было нельзя, так как длинная арифметика нужна была для микроконтроллеров без операционной системы и кучи. Пришлось написать свою библиотеку С++ шаблонов для работы с длинными целыми числами. Вот ссылка:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/muntl/?source=frontpage&position=5

Там в архиве есть и описание на русском языке.